# 'update_grid' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have written model.py and views.py.When I add the json variable from Admin it gives following error

`'update_grid' object has no attribute 'title'`

My views.py

```
def save_grid(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            grid = update_grid(data=data)
            grid.save()
            return HttpResponse('success') # if everything is OK
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from jsonfield import JSONField



class update_grid(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My JSON variable is of the form

```
 [{"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":1,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":2,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":1,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":5,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":6,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here uses instance variable `title`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

When Python 'looks' through your vars it sees that `self.title` was never declared, hence you get an error.
To fix it I would add title to your model:

```
class update_grid(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    data = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I hope it helps